# Twilio : Sort Channel based on last message time

Tags: ios, twilio, twilio-api

I am using **Twilio** chat SDK in my iPhone application.
I am trying to sort all channels list based on last message timestamp, is there any way to achieve this? Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The SDK doesn't currently have a way to sort channels. Your best bet is to load all the channels into an array and sort them yourself.

Comment: can you please tell me how I get to know the last message time in channel so I will sort it. and can we update the channel attributes while adding a message.

Comment: You'd need the last message from the list of messages to get the time for it. As for updating channel attributes, you could make an update at the same time as adding a message, using the channel object's [`setAttributes`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/chat/releases/2.2.0/docs/Classes/TCHChannel.html#//api/name/setAttributes:completion:) method.

Comment: Thanks for your quick support but I am trying the same but getting error signal.sdk.domain.error error 102. ios sdk while setting the channel attributes

Comment: That sounds like a new question then. Could you ask a new question on stack overflow and include the code that you are using and the error? Make sure it's tagged "twilio" and I'll find it.

Comment: @ philnash can you please check I have added new question for attribute issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48181384/twilio-not-able-to-set-channel-attribute

Comment: So how can we sort channel in a way that the ones with new messages are seen before the not active ones? Like What's for instance. More over, I don't want to get all channels, i want to page the requests.

Comment: Hey @Francesco, I’m afraid all the answers on this page, including from other people, are the best advice on this right now.

Answer (score 1):

As @philnash said, currently the SDK doesn't have a way to sort channels. This is how I have sort on my own in `javascript`. In javascript SDK, the channel has the last message's timestamp which I used for sorting.
**No need to fetch the last message and then look for it's timestamp**.

```
const sortedChannels = channels.sort(function (a, b) {

 /** Sort based on the last message if not, consider the last update of the channel */
 return new Date(b.lastMessage ? b.lastMessage.timestamp : b.dateUpdated) - new 
 Date(a.lastMessage ?
    a.lastMessage.timestamp :
    a.dateCreated);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue like this:

```
    func sortChannels() {
        let sortSelector = #selector(NSDate.compare(_:))
        let descriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateUpdatedAsDate", ascending: false, selector: sortSelector)
        channels!.sort(using: [descriptor])
    }
```

Edit:
Twilio documentation is kind of confusing. Maybe a better solution is using `lastMessageDate`, as `dateUpdatedAsDate` seems to be for something else.

```
NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastMessageDate", ascending: false, selector: sortSelector)
```