# Twilio : Not able to set channel attribute

Tags: ios, twilio, twilio-api

I am using twilio chat sdk in my iPhone application, on twilio website I have settled role permission editChannelAttributes is true for creator. and trying to set attribute like

```
        TwilioChatHelper.sharedInstance.selectedChannel?.setAttributes(attr, completion: { (result) in
        print(result?.isSuccessful() ?? "Not able to set attributes")
    })
```

but getting error in result

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (signal.sdk.domain.error error 102.)
```

Please suggest me what I am missing.

Comment: check app name and other parameters should match with app plist.

Comment: Thanks @MAhipalSingh, but I think If those details are not proper then chat also won't work, creating channel, Chat are working fine, only issue while setting the channel attributes.

Comment: then you need to check "role permission" https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest/roles#action-update  and https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/permissions

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Mahipal Singh is definitely on the right track here, this is down to [roles and permissions in Twilio Chat](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/permissions).

A regular channel user role, by default, has the following permissions:

- `deleteOwnMessage`
- `editOwnMessage`
- `editOwnMessageAttributes`
- `leaveChannel`
- `sendMediaMessage`
- `sendMessage`

If you want all channel users to be able to update a channel's attributes, then you will need to use the [Roles REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest/roles) to either add the `editChannelAttributes` permission to the default channel role or create a new role with that permission that you then assign to your channel members.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks philnash, but that was not an issue I have done that setup properly
it seems the issue Is different, I am setting the last message Date, as a Date object so issue is coming, if I do with converting it into string it will work.

Comment: Ah, ok, glad you found the solution. I just took a look at [the documentation](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/chat/releases/2.2.0/docs/Classes/TCHChannel.html#//api/name/setAttributes:completion:) and sounds like that's definitely the case, it says that the supported types for the attributes dictionary are `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` and `NSNull`.