# How to do pagination on channels in twilio-programmable-chat?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I am using twilio javascript sdk for twilio-programmable-chat.

And I want to apply pagination to my channels result but I am not able to figure it out.

Here is my current code.

```
this.chatClient.getUserChannelDescriptors().then(paginator => {

  // All channels are fetched

})
```

I tried to pass a `pageSize` similar to how `getMessages(10)` work but it didn't work.

```
this.chatClient.getUserChannelDescriptors(10).then(paginator => {
 // The result was same, it fetched all the channels instead of just 10
})
```

I am looking for a example that how pagination can be done on channels.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Did you ever find the solution? Was trying to get the next page.

Comment: @user3779015 here you go https://stackoverflow.com/a/57431978/6696353

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've finally found a way how to do it.

It should be done recursively since we get the initial list by calling `getUserChannelDescriptors()` but then the rest of the records can be fetched by calling `nextPage()`;

```
async function processChannels(paginator) {

    // Now, if hasNextPage is true
    // call nextPage() to get the records instead of getUserChannelDescriptors()
    if (paginator.hasNextPage) {
        const nextPaginator = paginator.nextPage();
        processChannels(nextPaginator);
    } else {
        console.log("END OF RECORDS");
    }
}

async function getChannels() {
    const paginator = await chatClient.getUserChannelDescriptors();

    // Initiate the recursive function
    if (paginator.items) {
        await processChannels(paginator);
    }
}
```

And this is what you will get in each call.

Comment: Hi.. I am developing a chat room using twilio js and I am using getSubscribedChannels() to list all subscribed channels of a user . Need some advice if getUserChannelDescriptors() is better? Just curious why you are using getUserChannelDescriptors and not getSubscribedChannels().

Comment: Also, if you could please advice if the paginated result is sorted (by default) by the date of channel creation/updation or by the last message sent timestamp.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. `getUserChannelDescriptors()` gives the light version of the channels as opposed to `getSubscribedChannels()`, which gets the full version of the channels with all the details. @tsikka

Comment: 2. Be default channels are sorted by their creation/updation date. `https://stackoverflow.com/a/54784463/6696353`, this is how I've sorted them by the last message @tsikka

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah I referred to your answer on sorting. I am worried if I have 100 channels and I get latest 50 in first page, but I have a message in let's say 60th channel. I won't be able to see it in first page right? Although it's a newer message

Comment: One way to overcome this is to update the attributes on every new message. Which should alter the `updated_at`  and assuming that channels are sorted based on updated date, it might resolve the issue @tsikka

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/3.2.0/docs/Client.html#getUserChannelDescriptors), the `getUserChannelDescriptors` method doesn't take any arguments.

But you shouldn't have to do pagination manually, since the method returns a `Promise.<Paginator.<ChannelDescriptor>>` type..which means you should be able to get access to the Pagination features twilio provides.

Your `paginator.items` should have only the items in a single page.

**EDIT:** Basically the point is that your first snippet is correct. Unfortunately, twilio is not open source so I cannot check where they have defined the `page_size` exactly. But I would encourage you to create say a hundred mock channels, and then check the size of the `paginator.items` array.

Try this:

```
this.chatClient.getUserChannelDescriptors().then(paginator => {
  console.log(paginator.items, paginator.hasNextPage(), paginator.hasPrevPage());
})
```

The documentation for the Paginator class is [here](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/3.2.0/docs/Paginator.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer I sort of get your answer but not exactly, can you give me a small example how this pagination thing can be done?